# How to integrate this integral by contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\pi e^{-a}\text{ for all }a>0
\end{equation*} 
by using contour integral?

Comment: Please add from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate the analytic continuation:

$$f(z) = \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}$$

On the following contour.

[image]

There are 2 poles or order 1, but just one pole is contained in the region enclosed by $\Gamma$.

It has residue $\dfrac{1}{2e^a}$

According to the mighty residue theorem

$$\int_\Gamma \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}\text{d}z = 2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2e^a} = i \color{green}{\frac{\pi}{e^a}}$$

Then evaluate the integral over the contours:

Starting with $\Gamma_1$

$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}\text{d}z \right| \leqslant \int_0^{\pi} \frac{R^2e^{-R\sin \theta}}{R^2-a^2} \text{d} \theta$$

Where you can split $\int^\pi_0 e^{-R\sin\theta} \text{d} \theta$ as:

$$\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0 e^{-R\sin\theta} \text{d} \theta &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R\sin\theta} \text{d} \theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta} \text{d} \theta\\
& \leqslant \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R\frac{2}{\pi}{\theta}} \text{d} \theta \\
& \leqslant \frac{-\pi}{2R}(e^{-R}-1)
\end{align}$$

While $\Gamma_2$

$$\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}\text{d}x = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{x\cos{x}}{x^2+a^2}\text{d}x + i \cdot \color{green}{\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\text{d}x} $$

When taking the limit, the green parts will be identical and this proves the statement.

*You should also prove convergence of the last integral when taking the limit to infinity*

Comment: I have a question about the convergence on route 1. Shouldn't it be a integral of R^2/(R^2+a^2) from 0 to 2 pi since contour integral would give us a R there?

Comment: True, my bad! Hmm, that creates some extra issues, I'll look into it.